# how to kill jenkins job based on build condition and then again put in the build queue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There is a requirement in our Jenkins CI setup where in we need to kill a particular child job initiated by master job if a certain condition fails or if a particular file is present/not present on the specified path, that is mentioned as a part of the build step that would be executed and also again the same job needs to be put in the build queue so that again next time the condition can be checked and executed accordingly?

Comment: Any Jenkins plugin available that can support the above requirment?